# How can I run an application in background? - gomobile

Tags: android, mobile, go

There seems to be a java API but I'm not sure how this is supposed to work with [mobileapp](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/mobile/app). Is there any go binding or anything like that?

Comment: Read android developer guide about service here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: I'm not sure how that applies to gomobile. Is there any way we can call the Android API (Java) from Go?

Comment: My knowledge of this is pretty sketchy, but I think you can call Go from Java. You can construct the shell of an app in Java, and have it call the logic you wrote in Go. (I think that's how the Ivy Android app is done--but, again, my background there is mostly limited to skimming some conference slides.)